# Display a DXF file in angular

Tags: angular, dxf, dxflib

I am uploading a file of type dxf in my angular application and getting the text format of it. Later it is parsed using dxf-paser and it returns array of entities. Now I need to display this parsed dxf file in my angular application inside a div. how do I do it.

I have added a div in html file and trying to append the dxf parsed entities into it but it displays nothing. Can someone please help me figure out the issue here

**in Ts:**

on file upload

```
const file =$event.target.files[0];
this.fileText = await file.text();

convertToDxf() {
   var parser = new DxfParser();
   try{
     var dxf = parser.parseSync(this.fileText);
     console.log(dxf);
     this.isdxfConverted = true;
     const div = document.createElement("div");
     if(dxf !== null) {
       div.innerHTML = dxf.toString();
     }
     div.style.height = '500px';
     div.style.width = '100%';
     let container = document.getElementById('dxfDisplay');
     container?.append(div);
   }
   catch {

   }
```

**in HTML**

```
 <div *ngIf="isdxfConverted" style="min-height: 500px" id="dxfDisplay">

 </div>
```